# C# MongoDb add array elements to multiple subdocuments

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo document with a structure similar to this made up one:

```
{
   Group: "Some group",
   Members: [
     { Name: "First Member", Messages: [] },
     { Name: "Second Member", Messages: [] }
   ]
}
```

When a message is sent to a group, or to a subset of the group members, I need to add the message to each `Messages` array of each receiver of the message.

So, lets say I have the following list of messages to save:

```
[ 
  { Receiver: "First Member", Message: { Subject: "subject", Text: "..."}},
  { Receiver: "Second Member", Message: { Subject: "subject", Text: "..."}},
  { Receiver: "Second Member", Message: { Subject: "whatever", Text: "..."}},
]
```

I really need to find a way of adding these messages to the group document, without replacing the document, since there can be multiple updates happening at the same time.

The best way I've found, is a list of update statements and a bulkwrite:

```
var updates = messages
   .GroupBy(n => n.Receiver)
   .Select(g =>
        {
            var filter =
                Builders<Group>.Filter.Where(
                    doc => doc.group == "Some group" && m.Members.Any(m => m.Name == g.Key));
            var update = Builders<Group>.Update.PushEach(doc => doc.Members[-1].Message, g.AsEnumerable());

            return new UpdateOneModel<Group>(filter, update);
        });

var result = await collection.BulkWriteAsync(updates);
```

Is this the best way? Or is there any other way I should try?

Comment: very strange design. why not store group message in the group? what if same member exist in 10 groups?

Comment: Yea. Don't worry to much about the design. First of all `I have a mongo document with a structure similar to this made up one`. The actual domain and model is a little different, but the problem is the same: push elements to array of elements of array. Second - it's little I can do about the design anyway.